# JSTL choose not run

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, el

I would print the first link. But the program print the second one always.
I try to change `!= null` with `not empty` etc., but there is no change.

I print my object `abstractAttrezzatura.insieme`, and **it is not null and not empty**, so why this code doesn't work??

```
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${abstractAttrezzatura.insieme != null} ">    
    <a href="${urlInsieme}">${labelInsieme}  <img src="${urlTorna}" align="top" height="30" width="30"/></a>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <a href="${urlFoglioLavoro}">${labelFoglioLavoro}  <img src="${urlTorna}" align="top" height="30" width="30"/></a>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(@PathVariable("id") final Long id, final Model uiModel, final Locale locale, 
        @ModelAttribute("idFoglioLavoro") Long idFoglioLavoro) {
    AbstractVerbale  verbale = verbaleService.findById(id);
    uiModel.addAttribute("verbale", verbale);
    uiModel.addAttribute("abstractAttrezzatura", verbale.getAttrezzatura());
    uiModel.addAttribute("itemId", verbale.getId());
    uiModel.addAttribute("idFoglioLavoro", idFoglioLavoro);

    return "verbale/show";
}
```

Comment: Show us where you put and attribute named `abstractAttrezzatura` into the request/session/servlet/page context.

Comment: I don't use that but I use a model

Comment: Show us how you use the `Model`.

Comment: Can you put in what .getAttrezzatura() object is?

Comment: Is an AbstractAttrezzatura object, is an Abstract class of my object.

Comment: Can you verify that its `insieme` is not `null`?

Comment: I had verified and is not null.

Comment: I would ask you to show that as well. Put a log statement in your `show` method printing it out. Also, just to confirm, is the JSP snippet in `verable/show` view?

Comment: We're triyng to find out what insieme is, try doing 'ne null' or try the reverse eq null to see if it actually does the first statement with it.

Comment: Just a quick thing, you don't need to have </a> at the end of your link tags as you've already closed them inside the original <a do stuff />

Comment: @VeenarM I close first the `<img src../>` and last the `<a href>` tag.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Enter in the correct show. In my view see ever the second choise, the object `insieme` is not null, but the behavior is incorrect.

Comment: I want you to prove that. How do you know it isn't null?

Comment: Read the question please.. **I print my object abstractAttrezzatura.insieme, and it is not null and not empty, so why this code doesn't work??**

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try "not empty" like:

```
<c:when test="${not empty abstractAttrezzatura.insieme} ">
```

Comment: Try it and no change.

Comment: i think u better try printing out the value just to make sure you're getting what you expect. <c:out value="${abstractAttrezzatura.insieme}" /> or just ${abstractAttrezzatura.insieme} to see if the value is really what you're expecting.

Comment: Yes, show the correct value. I had resolved, to check in the controller and pass a boolean in the view. I don't like it, but is only solution I had found.